# Problem with DocuSign Signature appliances DSA Rest Examples

Tags: docusignapi

I want to integrate automatic digital signature capabilities in my application. I signed-up for DocuSign sandbox account and tried to build and run example code from https://github.com/docusign/docusign-signature-appliance-api-recipes/tree/master/dsa-rest/Hello-World-examples

While running java hello-world example I am getting error as

```
Feb 09, 2021 9:01:00 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://prime-dsa-devctr.docusign.net:8081: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
Feb 09, 2021 9:01:00 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
```

I tried running C# code also , but get similar error in calling REST Endpoint "https://prime-dsa-devctr.docusign.net:8081/sapiws/v1/digital_signature"

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive
```

am I missing something here? I tried changing user credential used in code, but still error does not change.

Comment: This appears to be a transient service-related issue, and not a programming issue. As such, it doesn't really fit on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The service is up and running

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** the issue should be resolved now.

The DSA team is working on this, this is not your issue. It's down at least when I'm typing this answer. I'll update it as soon as it's back up.

Comment: FYI - since this is a service issue, and not programming-related (and transient), this really isn't the place for such a question. I would suggest just putting a comment under the question, rather than posting/updating an answer (and the question itself will likely be closed as off-topic soon as well).

Comment: Completely agree David, just wanted to help Milind as much as possible.